# Customer attributes not saving from admin

Tags: magento2, customer, save

I've created custom customer attribues

```
        $attributeCodes = [
            ['code' => 'customer_company' , 'label'=> 'Societe'],
            ['code' => 'customer_siret', 'label'=> 'Siret'],
            ['code' => 'customer_forme_juridique','label' => 'Forme Juridique'],
            ['code' => 'customer_tva', 'label' => 'TVA']
        ];
        foreach ($attributeCodes as $attr){
            $attributeCode = $attr['code'];
            $attributeLabel = $attr['label'];
            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                Customer::ENTITY,
                $attributeCode,
                [
                    'type'         => 'varchar',
                    'label'        => $attributeLabel,
                    'input'        => 'text',
                    'required'     => false,
                    'visible'      => true,
                    'user_defined' => true,
                    'position'     => 999,
                    'system'       => 0,
                ]
            );
            $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode);
            $attribute->setData(
                'used_in_forms',
                ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_edit']

            );
            $attribute->save();
        }
```

THey are now appearing in the customer edit form.

But when I save them, I don't see any values saved in `customer_entity_varchar` for any of these attributes

That being said if i'm going to magento 2 core code : `src/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Save.php` and dumping  there

```
            $customerData = $this->_extractCustomerData();
            var_dump($customerData);
```

At this point the total is in the customerData so I don't get why she isn't saved after all (I don't have any error message neither).

What am I missing there ?

Answer (score 0):

you can take reference from this url

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-add-customer-attribute-programmatically.html